# multiple fragments - where to commit them?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-nested-fragment

I'm trying to wrap my head around how and where i should be setting up my fragments.

**Use case senario i'm trying to implement**

- I have a mainActivity that has a `bottomNigationView` widget that will open different fragments (fragment A, B and C)
- In **FragmentB** i ask the user to input some information, then they click the `next` button which should should load another fragment lets say called **FragmentB2**
- **FragmentB2** should carry over some information that the user imputed from **FragmentB**

---

My question is, should i be making the fragment transactions of both fragments B and B2 in the mainActivity? Since i read online that it's not good practice to have nested fragments.

Currently, what i have is inside of FragmentB, i start a fragment transactions when the `next` button is clicked, so that it creates and goes to FragmentB2. I think this is whats called a *nested Fragment*, correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you're near the beginning of your project, this is a great time to look into using a navigation controller from google's new architecture components.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/

This will let you abstract the management of these individual stacks of fragments. I know this is a bit of a tangential response, but if you are worried about nesting, maybe take a step back and see if you can put together the higher level scaffolding of your navigation first.